# Dry Suit Shorts: Do they exist?

Tags: equipment, scuba-diving, water-sports

Is it possible to purchase dry shorts/bottoms that keep the water out in a similar way that a dry suit does?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know they don't exist.

First of all because of the constructional borders: How would you build them? When you think about it, normal shorts end up around your knees. The problem is that your muscles aren't that static in their shape, so how would you prevent the water from flowing in?

Secondly, dry-suits are made for cold water and for diving for a longer time below 10°C. So it wouldn't make any sense to construct one as shorts.

Comment: While I doubt they exist and they would likely be impractical,  it should be possible to make them. Latex seals could be used, just placed on the biceps and thighs.

Answer (score 0):

You could theoretically get semi-dry shorts but not full dry. I've never seen any though. By the time you're on shorts you might as well go for neoprene and accept that you're getting wet.

Answer (score -1):

It does not exists, and even if it did, it would probably be one of the worst items to dive with, as you would have a floating air bubble that would make you float feets first. You would have trouble keeping your buoyancy to neutral, and risk breathlessness for trying too much.

Comment: This answer is not off topic as it describes another reason why the asked item does not exists. It does not break any rule found at https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers. Moreover, this answer brings forward a serious safety concern with the equipement seeked, I find important to point it out.